# Rotate rectangle around center on mouse drag

Tags: javascript

I want to make a rectangle rotate around its center as in this code. The problem is that the rectangle rotates on mouse drag on any area.
I want the rectangle to rotate on its position when the mouse drags it only not any mouse drag rotates it.
I am using the **p5.js** library.

If there any code that rotates rectangle around its center on the mouse drag that please share it with me.

Link of code: https://editor.p5js.org/jwglazebrook/sketches/p2pnhPSZE

```
let angle = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  push();
  translate(150, 150);
  rotate(angle);
  
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  rect(-100, -75, 200, 150);
  
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  strokeWeight(5);
  line(-100, -75, 100, -75);
  
  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  point(0, 0);
  
  pop();
}

function mouseDragged() {
  m_angle = atan2(mouseY - 150, mouseX - 150);
  angle = /* MAGIC FORMULA HERE */ m_angle;
}
```

Code of 2 circle

```
let angle = 0.6;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

}

function draw() {
 
  background(204, 226, 225);    // Light blue color
  fill(204, 226, 225);         // Blue color

  push();
  translate(150, 150);
  rotate(angle);
  
  circle(-50,0,100);
  circle(50,0,100);

  pop(); 
  
 
  line(100, 100, 200, 200);
}

function mouseDragged() {
  
  m_angle = atan2(mouseY - 150, mouseX - 150);
  angle =  m_angle;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/graphilla/pen/MybXwy check this. it's created  with jquery and jquery UI

Comment: This code doesn't do what I want. I want the rectangle to be fixed from the center and with mouse drag, the rectangle rotates on its position fixed.  Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please how can I make this circle not draggable and fixed on its position

Comment: just remove the div id with drag. so it won't be able to drag. but since you only need to rotate this will be enough for you .http://jsfiddle.net/Symphony/pfs12rye/ .  i am just referring links so you can check.these are not my own works that why I put them as comments :)

Comment: Can we draw 2 circles inside rectangle so they rotate with each other like in this code by p5.js above code of 2 circles I want the circles to rotate with mouse drag on them only not on any area

Comment: My target is to rotate 2 circles with each on-axis like the above code of 2 circles. Thanks